# Separate second number from text using Excel formula

Tags: excel-formula

I have project number in cell `I132`. Values are like (just an example what they can be):

```
654321 - 9000 Workshop
654321 - 2100 Subcontractor
654321 - 3500 Unrealistic
654321 - 6400 Flawless victory
```

I have only one value in `I132` (for example) `654321 - 9000 Workshop`. How to separate second number after `-` (9000) using Excel formula?

I have tried with no success:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ";I132;FIND(" ";I132;1)+1));I132;LEFT(I132;FIND(" ";I132;FIND(" ";I132;1)+1)))
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have edited my question. List is just an example what values can be. There is only one value in mentioned cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your data has this same format as your posted examples *(6 digit number followed by space dash space)*, then use:

```
=MID(A1,10,4)
```

**EDIT:**

If the first number is not always **6** characters long, use:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(" - ",A1)+3,4)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is at the moment however at some point in the future there can be 7 and 8 digits. Is it possible to make more flexible formula?

Comment: @user7202022  See my EDIT.

Answer (score 1):

To make it very generic, we can use the following version:

```
=LEFT(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+2,1000),FIND(" ",MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+2,1000))-1)
```

This way it will work even if the first and second numbers have more than 6 and 4 digits. This is basing on the assumption that it will have a dash between the numbers and after the second number is a blank space.

Answer (score 0):

If then format is always the same, with 4 digits numbers, formula should be:

```
=MID(I132, FIND("-", I132) + 2, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your data has the same structure across board which is

`random number` + `(space)-(space)` + `random number` + `(space)` + `word`

You can use the following formula to find the second number:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[text()='-']/following-sibling::*[1]")
```

[image: FILTERXML]

For the logic behind this formula you may give a read to this article: [Extract Words with FILTERXML](https://chandoo.org/wp/extract-words-with-filterxml/).

Cheers :)